# How to get a mortgage loan with non-traditional employment

Tags: mortgage-qualification

How to get a mortgage loan when working for a temp agency? Every place I've called has turned me down due to my job.  Need advice on where to turn to get mortgage loan.

Comment: please include your country.

Comment: The answer may be that you need to wait until you have more savings or s better paying job...

Comment: Or have a job where you're a W2 employee.  Mortgage lenders just don't like irregular incomes or self-employed people, even if that self-employment income is quite large. Try searching for "Ben Bernanke can't get mortgage" for an interesting incidence of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to find a lender if you can document stability of income. You don't say how long you have been working for the temp agency, but if you can show three years of income taxes with stable income from the temp agency, you may be able to make a case.

Read more here:
http://homeguides.sfgate.com/can-mortgage-temporary-employment-59953.html